# Changing pluralized endpoint in SailsJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, sails.js, pluralize

Currently i have all my routes in Sails to be pluralized because im using ember. However i have an issue where Sails is not pluralizing a word properly.

I have a `quiz` model, and when i do a `findAll` on quiz it returns nothing. Come to find out after attempting to visit my sails endpoint `/api/v1/quizzes` i get nothing back. So i went ahead and tried `/api/v1/quizs` and it returns to me

> {     "quizzes": [ array, of, my, quizzes]  }

Does anyone know how i can force SailsJS to give the correct pluralized endpoint? Or do i need to just create the endpoint manually to return the data?

Comment: I hope the answer below helps. If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to override the blueprints routes and use custom routes for the quiz api

```
# routes.js

'get /quizzes/:id?': 'QuizController.find',
'post /quizzes': 'QuizController.create',
'put /quizzes/:id': 'QuizController.update',
'delete /quizzes/:id': 'QuizController.destroy',
```